# How i can add tow line on ListView With Section Header in android?

Tags: android

i have problem with my app, i don't know exactly where is problem?
i can't when i want to put tow line " mAdapter.addItem("Item 1","Item 888"); " just one line.
Could anyone help me please.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity  {

private CustomAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem("Second Item on the list");
    mAdapter.addItem("Item 1","Item 888");
    mAdapter.addItem("Item 2","Item 888");
    mAdapter.addItem("Item 3","Item 888");
    mAdapter.addItem("Item 4","Item 888");
    mAdapter.addItem("Item 5","Item 888");

    mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem("Second Item on the list1");
    mAdapter.addItem("Item 6","Item 888");
    mAdapter.addItem("Item 7","Item 888");
    mAdapter.addItem("Item 8","Item 888");
    mAdapter.addItem("Item 9","Item 888");
    mAdapter.addItem("Item 10","Item 888");

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

}
}
```

//==================================================================//

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void addItem(final String item1) {
    mData.add(item1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSectionHeaderItem(final String item) {
    mData.add(item);
    sectionHeader.add(mData.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams") 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (rowType) {


        case TYPE_ITEM:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_m, null); //snippet_item1
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_content1); // here problem ?
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_content2); // here problem ?
            break;


        case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_m, null); //snippet_item2
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.separator);
            break;


        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}

}
```

//===========================================================//

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

//=====================================================//

header_m.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40sp"
android:background="#140000"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:gravity="center"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:textColor="#EB000B"
android:id="@+id/separator"
 />
```

//==================================================//

list_item_m

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_content1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="left"



    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_content2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_content1"

    />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

//========================================================//

Comment: what do you what to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `CustomAdapter` does not have a function with signature `addItem(String, String)`, it does have one with signature `addItem(String)`.

So I think you are getting compile errors on these lines:

```
mAdapter.addItem("Item 1","Item 888");
mAdapter.addItem("Item 2","Item 888");
mAdapter.addItem("Item 3","Item 888");
...
```

You are trying to call the `addItem()` function with two String arguments and that does not exist. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish but you can get it to compile by changing those lines to this:

```
mAdapter.addItem("Item 1");
mAdapter.addItem("Item 2");
mAdapter.addItem("Item 3");
...
```

Good luck.